# Scrum meeting - dealing with the last question

Tags: agile, scrum

In the 5/15 minute scrum meeting the 3 questions are asked.

For the last question
"what impediments are getting in your way"

If a dev has problems - the xyz is going to have problems, this is likely going to draw the meeting out past 15 mins and could go into a hour long discussion.

Is it the scrum masters job to help this user, is there something to stop this from going on more than 15 mins.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Remind everyone that the daily scrum meeting needs to be short, and ask them to briefly list their impediments during the meeting.

Then, if any impediments need a lot of discussion, schedule a meeting with those involved immediately after the scrum to discuss the details. Everyone else can get on with their day while you work out how to remove the impediment.

Comment: This is what we used to do. The Daily Scrum was scheduled for half an hour because of that reason, so that whenever some issues were raised that needed discussing, those who didn't have any interest in the matter could go back to work and the rest could stay and discuss it in detail.

Answer (score 2):

If the impediments can be resolved quickly (in a couple of min) - deal with it at the stand-up meeting, if it requires more time to resolve - park it and deal with it after the meeting in the order to priority.

Stand-ups should be time-boxed and kept under 15min in order to be effective for the whole scrum team. When the team gets into routine of ~15 min daily standups, then having a longer one once in a while is not a big deal...

Answer (score 1):

In our dailies, if someone says that he has a problem that may require a long time to investigate\ solve, the scrum master just refers to the relevant person (who can help), from\ outside of the scrum team, and suggests to close the issue out of the meeting. Dailies, as the scrum methodology, are intended for the WHOLE team. A specific problem which can't contribute to others, should be managed out of the scrum meetings.